# zedgraph doesnt apply the changes to the myPane

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I am trying to create a visual representation of my data, I have already populated point pair lists and I am creating my chart as follows:

```
public void CreateChart(ZedGraphControl zgc)
    {
        GraphPane myPane = zgc.GraphPane;

        //set the title and axis labels
        myPane.Title.Text = "Graph";
        myPane.XAxis.Title.Text = "Width";
        myPane.YAxis.Title.Text = "Height";


        //create curves
        BarItem myCurve = myPane.AddBar("1", pointPairList1, Color.Blue);
        BarItem myCurve2 = myPane.AddBar("2", pointPairList2, Color.Red);

        zgc.AxisChange();

    }
```

When I call the method CreateChart(chart1) no changes are made to the graph, even the titles dont get updated..
Can anyone spot my mistake?

ANSWER:

```
        chart1.AxisChange();
        chart1.Invalidate();
        chart1.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
    zgc.refresh();
```

or

```
    zgc.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an event `ZedGraphWeb1_RenderGraph` then put all you code inside that block.